# What's the best way to allow user to upload and edit file before uploading to Amazon S3?

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I'm learning how to write a web app similar to [imgur](http://imgur.com). The app will allow the user to do basic photo edits after it's uploaded. My question is, should I upload to my server, allow user to edit photo, then upload to Amazon S3 OR upload to S3, allow user to edit photo, and then update new changes back to original file that's hosted on Amazon S3.

What route do I take that's more efficient? Is there a way to do it that I don't know?

Comment: Do you want to save the original photo to S3 or you want to just save just the processed photo to S3.

Comment: My plan is to have a version control in place to track all changes in the future. Right now, I only want to save and overwrite the original with the new edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your use case the best way to go is upload and process the image on server first and then move the processed image to S3 while deleting the original from the server. This will be more fast and economical way to go.

If you upload original to S3 and then bring it to the server for processing and then again move the processed image to S3 there will be more latency and data transfer involved in this way. Also remember you get charged for S3 data transfer too and here you will get charged three times. User uploads Image to S3 + you bring that image to EC2 for processing + you re-upload processed image back to S3.